# How can I have Skype run a command when I get a call?

Tags: sound, skype, hdmi

I'd like to have my Linux based machine run a command when Skype receives a call. Is this possible?

Use case: use HDMI audio for Raspberry Pi but play notification audio through analog jack in case TV is using a different HDMI device on an HDMI switch.

Comment: I think there would be something related to sound. Skype somehow has to signal to the system to use sound. I'll try to work on a script, I'll see what can be done. Are there any specific requirements you have ?

Comment: Nothing in particular. I know using omxplayer a user can select the analog jack even if the Pi is using HDMI to output audio otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A **Hack-ish** way to achieve this would be to find out the title of the window which appears when there is an incoming call and use wmctrl to check if such a window is present.

You can write a script and then use cron or your own logic to run this script at fixed intervals.

I don't know the format of Skype incoming call window's title, but the overall script could be something like this (if written in python)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

# Change below line according to skype window title
# You might need to use regex in case the title has usernames 
command = r"wmctrl -xl | grep 'Skype - Incoming'"
output = system.exec_command(command, getOutput=True)

if output != "":
    # Play sound here
    pass
```